# Is it necessary to utilize the IntPtr constructor to set an IntPtr to equal another IntPtr?

Tags: c#, intptr

I am currently refactoring an application to 64 bit and I am trying to understand a specific use of the IntPtr. The code that I am trying to understand is in the form of:

```
IntPtr a = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SomeObjectSize); //SomeObjectSize is calculated based on some standard
IntPtr b = IntPtr(a.ToInt32());
```

Now at first blush I figured I could just change `a.ToInt32()` to `a.ToInt64()`, which worked for instances where an `int` needed to go into an `IntPtr`, but since `a` and `b` are both `IntPtr` types, couldn't I just use `IntPtr b = a;` since `IntPtr` is a value type? I figure this will keep me from having to check for 64 bit or 32 bit builds in this kind of situation and the MSDN docs don't seem to imply any magic in the `IntPtr` constructor.

Basically my question is why would I use

```
IntPtr a = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SomeObjectSize);
IntPtr b = IntPtr(a.ToInt32());
```

over

```
IntPtr a = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SomeObjectSize);
IntPtr b = a;
```

?

Comment: It you had a 16 bit address from Windows 95 you would need to make it a 32 bit address, but not a 64 bit address to 32.  The IntPtr is only 32 bit for compatibility and taking a 64 bit address and making it 32 bit would cause exceptions.

Comment: @jdweng the exact problem i am dealing with is compiling in 64 bit, i am getting arithmetic overflow exceptions on lines with `IntPtr(a.ToInt32())`

Comment: Arithmetic Overflow has nothing to do with IntPtr.  The number return from an IntPtr can be any size (8,16,32,64).  The error is occurring with the math you are doing with the results.  If you are adding two int16 your code is changing [a.ToInt32()] the int16 to an int32  So an int32 + int32 will give an error if the results is only suppose to be a int16.

Comment: Just don't use that constructor, a simple assignment is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not only can use

```
IntPtr b = a;
```

to hold the information used to obtain a pointer, but you should use this to ensure compatibility for different platforms.`IntPtr` is platform specific type (see [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)) and its size depends on the platform bitness to automatically fit the pointer size.

However, the `IntPtr` is multipurpose type and it's intended not only to keep pointers information but also for various Windows API handles in order to be used in Win API interoperations (this however is mainly utilized by runtime and CTS and rarely by external applications). Many of the these handles (such as windows handles, icon handles, file handles, registry handles, etc.) have 32-bit size and that's where the `IntPtr` should be initialized with specifically sized integer and where the `IntPtr(int value)` constructor comes into play.