# python.NET upgrade to python 3.7: IntPtr to numpy array constructor not matching given arguments anymore

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, python.net, intptr

The following code to [copy a .NET array to a numpy array](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2014-May/001525.html) works in python 2.7.17 but not anymore in python 3.7.7:

```
import clr, numpy
from System import Array, Int32, IntPtr
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import Marshal

n = 10
net_arr = Array.CreateInstance(Int32, n)
for i in range(0, n): net_arr[i] = i

np_arr = numpy.zeros([n], int)
np_ptr = IntPtr.__overloads__[int](np_arr.__array_interface__['data'][0])
Marshal.Copy(net_arr, 0, np_ptr, net_arr.Length)
print(np_arr)

# python2 output:
[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]

# python3 output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    np_ptr = IntPtr.__overloads__[int](np_arr.__array_interface__['data'][0])
TypeError: no constructor matches given arguments
```

I'm aware that there were some changes to python types from 2 to 3 but searching and playing around with the constructor didn't help me find a solution. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Int64:

```
from System import Array, Int32, Int64, IntPtr
...
IntPtr.__overloads__[Int64](np_arr.__array_interface__['data'][0])
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a working solution! May it help many others along the way. I upvoted but did not make this accepted answer because in my timeit tests with large array sizes the GCHandle approach above was multiple times faster.

Comment: Actually, I made it the accepted answer because it does answer the question. Anyone looking to improve speed should use the GCHandle approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround**

(from [Python.NET Mailing List](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2014-May/001526.html)) which is even faster because the pointer is directly accessed and the copy operation avoided:

```
import ctypes
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import GCHandle, GCHandleType

net_hndl = GCHandle.Alloc(net_arr, GCHandleType.Pinned)
try:
    net_ptr = net_hndl.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64() # ToInt32 gave an Overflow Error
    bufType = ctypes.c_int32 * len(net_arr)
    cbuf    = bufType.from_address(net_ptr)
    np_arr  = numpy.frombuffer(cbuf, dtype=cbuf._type_)
finally:
    if net_hndl.IsAllocated: net_hndl.Free()
```

However, it doesn't explain the original problem. As stated in the original post it's likely related to the [python integer changes from version 2 to 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers) and maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636965/is-it-necessary-to-utilize-the-intptr-constructor-to-set-an-intptr-to-equal-anot), but I couldn't figure out a valid [IntPtr constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8).

If anybody can bring it together I would still appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the solutions worked, I am actually trying to get a pointer to a numpy array and pass it on to a .NET5 C# library. Currently working with pythonnet 3 dev.
The constructor for IntPtr refuses to work either with int or Int64 parameters. I solved it by calling the Parse() constructor and passing the string representing the numpy array address:

```
v = np.zeros(256)
data_addr = str(v.__array_interface__['data'][0])
ptr = System.IntPtr.Parse(data_addr)
```